# can't require curb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Im sure this is another forehead slapper that will turn my face red, but for some reason I'm getting an error when I try to use `require 'curb'` at the top of my ruby script or in irb:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- curb
```

I ran `sudo gem install curb` and found I had to run `sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls-dev` in order to get the gem install to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: well i found AN answer: if I add `require 'rubygems'` everything seems ok. Is this a good idea though?

Comment: Yes. If you are not using a Gemfine (bundler), when you use gems you MUST require rubygems for them to work.

Comment: Please, answer and accept your own answer to close the question properly, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not using a bundler, I had to add `require 'rubygems'` at the beginning of my list of requires.